# Mount fuse.mergerfs in udev script

Tags: systemd, udev, unionfs

I use a udev rule to recognize when a specific USB stick is plugged. When it's plugged in, a bash script is started which mounts some devices. That works very well after I did some changes to the systemd-udev service as described [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/330094/udev-rule-to-mount-disk-does-not-work).

However, one of the mounts fail. It is a fuse-mergerfs mount. The command itself seems to succeed, but when doing an `ls` on the mount folder I get a strange output and I cannot access the folder:

```
d?????????  ? ?    ?       ?            ? mountpoint
```

But if I run the mount command manually from the terminal everything is fine.

It also doesn't matter if the stick is plugged in during boot or if I plug it in after the system has already started. Mounting the fuse-mergerfs device does not work when `mount` is called by the udev script.

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [Using RUN in udev rules] is only suitable for short-lived scripts, as they will be killed if they are stil running after a timeout period.

I.e. the FUSE background process that implements your filesystem gets killed.

One alternative that comes to mind: if you have the `systemd-mount` command, you could try using that in place of your `mount` command.  It will create a transient `.mount` unit (as opposed to a `.service` unit), and run the `mount` program inside that unit.

The source I am quoting tries to provide a more general solution for long-running processes:

> https://yakking.branchable.com/posts/systemd-2-udevd/
>
> If you need a longer-running service, then you should integrate it
>   with a systemd unit, by defining the unit like:
>
> ```
> cat >/etc/systemd/system/my-service@.service <<'EOF'
> [Unit]
> Description=My Service
> [Service]
> Type=simple
> ExecStart=/path/to/your/script %I
> EOF
> ```
>
> And add `ENV{SYSTEMD_WANTS}="my-service@%k.service"` to the udev rule.
>
> This will run /path/to/your/script and pass it the path to the device
>   that has just appeared.

**Unfortunately the above instructions are not correct for your case**.

Your problem is not that your script itself took too long before returning.  The problem is that your script returns after starting a "background process"; the process that implements your FUSE filesystem.  When the script finishes, `systemd` thinks it needs to clean up, and kill all the left-over processes which were started by the script.

This case is very similar to a legacy sysvinit script.  So we can use the same solution they do:

When you write a systemd service to `mount` a FUSE filesystem, do not use  `Type=simple` or `Type=oneshot`.  Use `Type=forking` instead.

Comment: It doesn't look like it's killed. E.g. if I add a sleep to the script, the PC hangs for that amount of time during boot. So, the timeout seems to be high enough.However, I tried it with a systemd service. It executes my script, too. And again, all mounts work, except for the fuse.mergerfs mount. This time, no weird "????" are shown, but the device is mounted neither.

Comment: @Biggie regarding the second part only: only FUSE mounts require a long-running process.  If none of the other mounts are FUSE mounts, that would explain the difference.

Comment: I do not get any error message. The mount command succeeds with exit code 0 :)

Comment: "I cannot access the folder". What error message do you get when you try to access the folder?

Comment: It shows "Der Socket ist nicht verbunden". In english something like: "Socket ist not connected" or maybe "Transport endpoint" instead of socket ;)

Comment: However, this happens only when using RUN. When using a systemd service I can enter the folder. It's empty. Running `mount` shows that nothing is mounted there

Comment: Ahh :-). I believe that's the same error yes, although Google doesn't know much about it. It did find one likely example of the problem my current answer describes (ntfs-3g is implemented as a FUSE filesystem): https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=163175  Anyway, I'm trying to think about why your service doesn't do anything, but it is very mysterious :-).  I take it the script works to mount the device when you run the script manually, and not from the systemd service.

Comment: Yep, running the script manually works without any problems.

Comment: You made my day :) It works! Thank you so much!
Maybe add this to your answer-text above ;)

Comment: Great :-).  I've edited the answer to show the working solution.