# Udev script stops after first command

Tags: shell-script, udev

My udev rule points to a bash script with two commands.
While the first command `echo` runs fine, the second line `ifuse` seems not to be executed.

`$ cat /etc/udev/rules.d/test.rules`

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ENV{PRODUCT}=="5ac/12a8/804", ENV{INTERFACE}=="255/253/1" RUN+="/bin/sh /home/user/test.sh"
```

`$ cat /home/user/test.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Phone connected" >> /home/user/test.log
sleep 3
/usr/bin/ifuse /home/user/media/iOS
```

Remarks:

- `ifuse` works if I execute the script manually: `$ sh test.sh`
- Replacing the udev `RUN+` statement with `"/bin/su user -c /home/user/test.sh"` doesn't help
- Man page ifuse: https://www.mankier.com/1/ifuse

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/497266/mount-fuse-mergerfs-in-udev-script / https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/507150/29483

Comment: Can you add the output of udevadm info --attribute-walk (device path) in your answer